# Iphone app is rejected due to copyright violations

Tags: ios

I had submitted an i-phone app which is a Logo quiz based app but it was rejected because of copyright violations.
The logo quiz caters to the following categories
1) Company Logo
2) God logo
3) Cartoon Character Logo
4) Super Hero Logos
5) Country Flag Logos
Let me know what i need to do in order to get my app approved.

Below is the Message From Apple for rejecting my app:

8.1 - Apps must comply with all terms and conditions explained in the Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights and the Apple Trademark List
8.5 - Apps may not use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrights, patents or violate 3rd party terms of use. Authorization to use such material must be provided upon request
8.5 Details

Your app includes content or features that resemble well-known third-party marks, such as The Simpsons, Superman, etc., without the necessary authorization to use this material.

We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

Pursuant to your agreement with Apple, you represent and warrant that your application does not infringe the rights of another party, and that you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim that your application infringes another party's rights. Moreover, we may reject or remove your application for any reason, at our sole discretion.

Next Steps

Please provide documentary evidence of rights to use this content. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

Comment: In your app you are using words like Simpsons, Superman?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about review processes are deemed [off topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/916299)

Answer (score 1):

If your app contains those copyright violations, you are either going to have to remove any copyrighted material, or obtain express written permission from the owners of those materials and forward that information to Apple.

The information is there in Apple's response:

> Apps may not use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrights, patents or violate 3rd party terms of use.
>
> ---
>
> Authorization to use such material must be provided upon request
>
> ---
>
> Please provide documentary evidence of rights to use this content. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity

Comment: How do i get the documentary evidence, are there any websites from where i can take there permission?

Comment: You'll need to ask the copyright owners individually. You can't just take their art / logos / characters without asking.

Comment: Think of it like me walking into your house, taking a picture of your home, your family and your car, then posting loads of pictures of "my terrible home and awful car" on my blog. You don't want me degrading your life and work. Copyright owners are trying to do the same thing, they don't want to risk you using their image negatively. That's why you have to ask permission.